# orderBy worked in development but flawed in deployment

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a large variable on the main scope called cadwolfWorkspace which is an object. Each entry in the object is itself an object with another subobject called "Workspace". I want to sort by a property named "rank" within these objects. THis worked in my development environment, but something changed and I can't lock it down. I think I am missing something small because of too little sleep. Any suggestions?

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in cadwolfWorkspace | orderBy:Workspace.rank track by obj.Workspace.id" class="workspace_wrapper">
    <div class="workspace_line">
        <div ng-class="obj.Workspace.typeImageClass" ng-click="goToAddress(obj.Workspace.id)"></div>
        <div ng-class="obj.Workspace.typeClass" ng-hide="obj.Workspace.showEdit" ng-model="obj.Workspace.name" ng-click="obj.Workspace.showEdit=!obj.showEdit">{{obj.Workspace.name}}</div>
        <div ng-class="obj.Workspace.typeClass" ng-enter="obj.Workspace.showEdit=!obj.Workspace.showEdit; changeName(obj.Workspace.id)" ng-show="obj.Workspace.showEdit"><input class="myInput" ng-model="obj.Workspace.name"></div>
        <div class="workspace_copy" ng-click="copyItem(obj.Workspace.id)" ng-show="showEditOptions">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="workspace_move" ng-click="obj.Workspace.showMove=!obj.Workspace.showMove" ng-show="showEditOptions">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="workspace_delete" ng-click="deleteClick(obj.Workspace.id)" ng-show="showEditOptions">&nbsp</div>
        <div ng-click="checkClick(obj.Workspace.id)" ng-show="showEditOptions"><div ng-class="obj.Workspace.checkClass">&nbsp</div></div>
        <div class="workspace_showinfo" ng-click="obj.Workspace.showDesc=!obj.Workspace.showDesc">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="workspace_time">{{obj.Workspace.cdate | date : 'EEE, MMM d, y - h:mm a'}}</div>
        <div class="workspace_time">{{obj.Workspace.mdate | date : 'EEE, MMM d, y - h:mm a'}}</div>
        <div class="workspace_rank" ng-show="showEditOptions"><select class="workspace_rankselect" ng-model="obj.Workspace.newRank" ng-change="changeRank(obj.Workspace.id)" ><option value="{{obj.Workspace.rank}}" selected="selected">{{obj.Workspace.rank}}</option><option ng-repeat="myOption in cadwolfWorkspace" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option></select></div>
    </div>
    <div class="move_line" ng-show="obj.Workspace.showMove"><input type="text" class="moveaddress" ng-model="obj.Workspace.moveAddress" placeholder="Enter New Address" ng-enter="obj.showMove=!obj.showMove; moveItem(obj.Workspace.id, obj.Workspace.moveAddress)"></div>
    <div ng-class="obj.Workspace.descriptionClass" ng-show="obj.Workspace.showDesc">{{obj.Workspace.description}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a simple reference path that could be relative? Just a quick thought.